# Differential Equations - Elementary Application to Electric Circuits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An RL circuit has the following values: R=550 ohms, L=4 henrys and Esub0=110 volts. If i(0)= 0 in the circuit, when does the current reach 90% of its limiting value?

Using the formula:
E = Ri + Ldi/dt

I integrate it and substitute the given values. I got i=-27.5

I'm trying to put it in the formula.
I(t) = Ih(t) + Ii(t)
when i(t)= 90%i = 0.90i

I have to values for my I now.

I'm wondering how I can get the value of my other i? I only have this equation now..
0.90(t)= i-27.5
(Is that correct?)

According to someone's comment below, t=0.18
To get that answer, (my missing i should be 29.5) 
How can I solve for that?

Answer (score 2):

You have the differential equation $$\varepsilon=RI(t)+L\frac{\mathrm{d}I(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

The way to solve this kind of D.E. is first to solve the *homogeneous* version 
$$0=RI(t)+L\frac{\mathrm{d}I(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
the solution of which we could call $I_h(t)$, and then guess *any* solution (typically just a constant) to the inhomogeneous equation, which we could call $I_i(t)$. The general solution to the D.E. is then $$I(t)=I_h(t)+I_i(t)$$

Have a go at this and let me know if it is still causing you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we look at a series RL circuit.

We've to set up a system of the equations we know, where $\text{L}\space\wedge\space\text{R}\in\mathbb{R}^+$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{U}_{\text{R}}(t)+\text{U}_{\text{L}}(t)\\
\text{U}_{\text{R}}(t)=\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{R}}(t)\\
\text{U}_{\text{L}}(t)=\text{L}\cdot\text{I}'_{\text{L}}(t)\\
\text{I}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{I}_{\text{R}}(t)=\text{I}_{\text{L}}(t)
\end{cases}\therefore\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(t)+\text{L}\cdot\text{I}'_{\text{in}}(t)
$$

Using Laplace transform, we find that:

$$\text{U}_{\text{in}}(s)=\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(s)+\text{L}\cdot s\text{I}_{\text{in}}(s)-\text{L}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)\Longleftrightarrow\text{I}_{\text{in}}(s)=\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(s)+\text{L}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)}{\text{R}+\text{L}s}$$

Now, we know that $\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)$ is a DC (stable, $\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)\in\mathbb{R}$, where $0\le t<n$ where $n\to\infty$ ) voltage, so the Laplace transform equals: $\text{U}_{\text{in}}(s)=\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)}{s}$. So we get:

$$\text{I}_{\text{in}}(s)=\frac{\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)}{s}+\text{L}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)}{\text{R}+\text{L}s}$$

With inverse Laplace transform, we find:

$$\text{I}_{\text{in}}(t)=\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)+e^{-\frac{\text{R}t}{\text{L}}}\left(\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)-\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)\right)}{\text{R}}$$

So, we need to find the limit:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{I}_{\text{in}}(t)=\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)+0\cdot\left(\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)-\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)\right)}{\text{R}}=\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)}{\text{R}}$$

Now, for the $\text{n}$% of its limiting value:

$$\frac{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)+e^{-\frac{\text{R}t}{\text{L}}}\left(\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)-\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)\right)}{\text{R}}=\frac{\text{n}\cdot\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)}{100\text{R}}\Longleftrightarrow\color{red}{t=\frac{\text{L}\cdot\ln\left(-\frac{100\cdot(\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)-\text{R}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0))}{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)\cdot(\text{n}-100)}\right)}{\text{R}}}$$

When $\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)=0$, we get:

$$t=\frac{\text{L}\cdot\ln\left(-\frac{100\cdot(\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)-\text{R}\cdot0)}{\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)\cdot(\text{n}-100)}\right)}{\text{R}}=\frac{\text{L}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{100}{100-\text{n}}\right)}{\text{R}}$$

---

In your case, we know hat $\text{L}=4$, $\text{R}=550$, $\text{I}_{\text{in}}(0)=0$ and $\text{U}_{\text{in}}(t)=110$:

- $$\text{I}_{\text{in}}(t)=\frac{1-e^{-\frac{275t}{2}}}{5}$$
- $$t=\frac{2\cdot\ln\left(\frac{100}{100-\text{n}}\right)}{275}$$

Using the given value for $\text{n}$, we get:

$$t=\frac{2\ln(10)}{275}\approx0.0167461\to\text{I}_{\text{in}}\left(\frac{2\ln(10)}{275}\right)=\frac{9}{50}=0.18$$